# VB Error in Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am encountering an error in MS Excel when the following VB code is executed and the "Tracking Changes" feature is turned on:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If IsEmpty(Target) Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Empty
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 5).Value = Now()
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

It seems that I can enter data into the first 2 rows just fine but once I start populating data in the 3rd row and onwards, I get a error stating "run-time error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: This is in vb.net or in Excel's VBA editor (e.g. `Developer Tab -> Visual Basic`)? Can you add a breakpoint in the editor to discern where in the code this error is being thrown?

Comment: This works for me in Excel 2010. Note that with track changes ON in Excel 2010 (and probably 2007) you may not be able to use macros in the shared workbook file.

Comment: Also note you may want to use `Application.EnableEvents=False` at the beginning of this code, and `Application.EnableEvents=True` at the end of this code to prevent unnecessary looping (the if/else statement ALSO triggers the _Change event and fires the macro a second time, which is unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

Change Tracking forces the workbook to become Shared, which disables many features (e.g. you can't access VBA with Change Tracking enabled).

I'm not entirely sure *why* this error is being thrown, but a workaround to avoid seeing this message would be to `Resume Next` when an error occurs:

`On Error Resume Next`

Simply add this line of code about your first `If` block (`If Target.Column = 1 Then`). Please note that ideally you should want to discern the source of this issue and that this solution is a workaround, which might not be good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I get the error from row 2 onwards with this code and track changes turned on.  The code however seems to do what it is supposed to do regardless of the error, so I would advise an `On Error Resume Next` to work around.

This doesn't address any underlying problem with the change tracking and your changes may not be being tracked.